# Magic Square using Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: java, algorithm, particle-swarm, magic-square

I am given a n x n matrix where n ranges from 3 to 5.
The matrix is then assigned random values from 1-n^2.
Given the matrix I am to optimize the board such that I arrive to a solution of magic square.

Random board example: n = 3

```
    3 5 6
    1 7 8
    2 4 9
```

I have a little knowledge about PSO but I atleast know this:

```
1. Randomly initialize a set of particles at random positions in the search space;
2. Evaluate all positions and update the global best position and the personal best positions;
3. Update each velocity based on the relative position of the global best position, the current velocity of the particle, the personal best position of the particle and some random vector;
4. goto 2.
```

I have also been told that the problem is not suited for algorithms such as PSO, but I have no choice but use it for this problem since it is the algorithm required.

I am thinking the the particles are the numbers assigned in the array, but how do I evaluate its position and update the particles position?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an optimization problem to apply PSO. If you can define a *fitness function*, you may do the following:

For instance, your target sum is `20` and your fitness function is `f(currentSum) = |20 - currentSum|` for each row, column and diagonal.

You change the value of a square. After that, if changing that value decreased the value of `f()`, that means, your velocity should be directed to that solution. If it increased the value, you should go and look somewhere else.

You need two types of operations, which are **exploition** and **exploration**.

**Exploition** menas, searching the neighborhood for a solution. When a the value of a suqare is changed, looking for solutions such that making the row and the column of that value closer to your `targetSum`.

**Exploration** means, changing the whole picture. You do exploitation (usually after randomization of the whole board) after you apply this step.

For starters, you need to define

- Model of the problem
- What is a *solution*? How do you define a *solution*?
- Objective function
- Fitness function
- Velocity
- Poisiton
- Neighborhood
- Exploration

But my advice would be not to use PSO for a problem which is not an optimization problem. It is likely PSO will work with same performance as random search.